# Error: Could not find or load main class in Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, jar, package

I am trying to create an executable JAR file. After building a project I add a string to the manifest file: `Main-Class: com.zt.MainForm`

My main class located in the `com.zt` package. Class name: `MainForm.class`

I don't understand why am I getting this error. What am I doing wrong?

Manifest file contents:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.zt.MainForm
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Built-By: x
Build-Jdk: 12.0.2
```

Comment: and how is that being executed? which java version (`java -version`)? (seems like it was compiled with Java 12, needs at least Java 12 to run, *probably* default on system is 1.8) ((also running it from command line `java -jar file.jar` could give some additional error mesage))

Comment: is that class directly in the jar or packed into another jar inside the jar?

Comment: that class directly in the jar